# Duplicar un fila de una tabla de mi base de datos - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

AL crear un evento nuevo tengo una opcion que se habilita con un checkbox que es la de duplicar una cotizacion ya hecha de otro evento ya creado, me despliega la lista de que evento necesito duplicar esa cotizacion, tengo varias tablas donde se guarda una de ellas es una que se llama sections y necesito duplicar las filas que tengan ese id el cual se identifica por quotation_id para saber a que evento le pertenece, lo que tengo que hacer es hacer una consulta a esa tabla leer las filas que tengan ese id que necesito duplicar, duplicar esas filas (crear nuevos registros en mi fila), pero al duplicarlas necesito cambiar el quotation_id por el del evento nuevo que estoy creando.

No se si me explique bien. Alguna sugerencia de como podria hacerlo?

```
def duplicate_data
  if params[:showhide] == "1"
    event_selected = params[:event_id_select] #quotation_id
    event_current = Event.last.id #Id del nuevo evento que se esta creando

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el método `dup` para duplicar un registro en el modelo, modificarlo y luego guardarlo en la base de datos; por ejemplo, para duplicar una fila en el modelo `Section`:

```
def duplicate_data
  if params[:showhide] == "1"
    dup_section = Section.find_by(quotation_id: params[:event_id_select]).dup
    dup_section.quotation_id = Event.last.id
    dup_section.save!
  end
end
```

El código anterior funciona para 1 registro únicamente, si tienes muchos registros, puedes hacer lo mismo pero utilizando un *loop*:

```
def duplicate_data
  if params[:showhide] == "1"
    sections = Section.where(quotation_id: params[:event_id_select])
    event_id = Event.last.id

    sections.each do |section|
      dup_section = section.dup
      dup_section.quotation_id = event_id
      dup_section.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Para el ejemplo utilizo `save!` para que se genere un excepción en caso de error al guardar; sin embargo, para un código en producción generalmente es mejor utilizar `valid?` y luego `save`, evitando la excepción (y manejando cualquier posible error de datos).

Comment: Seria lo mismo si en lugar de usar el `dup`, mis datos modificados los guardo en otra fila de esta manera `dup_section = Section.last.id + 1` y luego el `save`?

Comment: No sería lo mismo, con `Section.last.id + 1` únicamente te devuelve un número: el `id` de la última fila `+1`, por lo que no podrías guardarlo; si ejecutas `dup_section.save` sería lo mismo que ejecutar `12.save` (tomando un `id` ejemplo de `12`). Para eso es `dup`, para _duplicar_ los datos de un registro sin afectarlo.

Comment: Ya lo pruebo gracias.