# Convertir a hash o subir a base de datos - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo esto que saqué de mi base de datos mediante:

```
nombre_secciones = Section.where(quotation_id: quotation_id_event)
```

Me sacó esto:

```
#<Section id: 12, name: "Seccion 1", created_at: "2018-07-24 15:06:34", updated_at: "2018-07-24 15:06:34", quotation_id: 62, order: 0>
```

Ya le he hecho las modificaciones que deseo pero ahora la quiero volver a subir a mi base de datos pero en una nueva fila pero no se muy bien cómo o ¿cómo podría transformarlo a un hash?.

Comment: No entiendo, ¿quieres duplicar ese registro? ¿o quieres actualizarlo?
Si quieres actualizarlo, debes hacer los cambios que corresponda y luego llamar a `.save` en tu registro, si quieres duplicarlo, llama a `.dup`

Answer (score 0):

> ... pero ahora la quiero volver a subir a mi base de datos pero en una
>   nueva fila...

La respuesta está en la primer pregunta que publicaste sobre este mismo tema; puedes verla [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/184723/42433).

> ... ¿cómo podría transformarlo a un hash?

Puedes utilizar el método `as_json`, el cual te regresará un arreglo de *hashes*. donde cada *hash* es un registro/fila del modelo en la base de datos:

```
Section.where(quotation_id: quotation_id_event).as_json
#[{"id"=>12, "name"=>"Seccion 1", "created_at"=>"2018-07-24 15:06:34", "updated_at"=>"2018-07-24 15:06:34", "quotation_id"=>62, "order"=>0}]
```